# How can I avoid exceeding the time limit in "while"? (python)

Tags: python, math, while-loop

I should figure out how iterations i need to come to loop

example:

0001 -> 0000 -> 0000                   - came to loop after 2 iterations;
4100 -> 8100 -> 6100 -> 2100 -> 4100   - came to loop after 4 iterations

My code:

```
n = int(input())

a = list(input().split())

for i in a:
        i = int(i)
        k = 1
        d = i
        i = i**2 // 100 % 10000
        while d != i:
            i = i**2 // 100 % 10000
            k = k + 1      
        print(k, end = ' ')
```

There is an exceeding time limit. How can I fix it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can speak few words about what you're doing.

Comment: _What_ time limit?

Comment: Python itself doesn't have any time limits. I expect you are executing this code in the context of some system (like an online homework submission system) that puts a time limit on the execution. A simple fix is to run the code in plain Python on your computer.

Comment: The `while` loop will run until `d == i`.  I don't see how `d` can be guaranteed to equal `i` for many values of `i` no matter how many times the loop runs. e.g.    If `i` ever becomes zero it will stay at zero. printing i in the loop to see what values it's taking may help identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you did not properly tell the computer to look back at "d==1". To properly do this, you need to add a continue statement at the end of the while loop. So, your code will look more like this:

```
n = int(input())

a = list(input().split())

for i in a:
    i = int(i)
    k = 1
    d = i
    i = i**2 // 100 % 10000
    while d != i:
        i = i**2 // 100 % 10000
        k = k + 1  
        continue    
    print(k, end = ' ')
```